Web Fonts Developer API is showing "Errors 100%"
Google Cloud Console
I added "Web Fonts Developer API" to my API and it shows — Errors 100%.
I have my API added to my Wordpress Divi theme options and the Google Map is working but the Google Fonts are showing error 100% in Google platform.
I am doing this to get Inter Tight. Divi theme only has Inter, not tight, without the Api.
DIVI INSTRUCTIONS
https://help.elegantthemes.com/en/articles/8548056-how-to-update-the-google-fonts-list-in-divi
Image: Screenshot of the error

you're doing something wrong perhaps - hard to say what really, since we can't see how you're using the API
